# What is 'write allocation' in GCP block storage docs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Reading the Google Cloud Platform docs on [Block storage performance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance#performance_factors) I came across the term 'write allocation' (expressed in MB/s, so it's apparently a kind of throughput limit) which is not explained there. To put it in context:
[image: Context for the term 'write allocation']

Googling the term hasn't turned any useful results either.

What does 'write allocation' mean in the context of block storage bandwidth limits?

Answer (score 1):

Above that table:

> The maximum write traffic that a VM instance can issue is the [network
>   egress cap](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/quota#per_instance) divided by a bandwidth multiplier that accounts for the
>   write bandwidth used by this redundancy and overhead.
>
> In a situation where persistent disk is competing with IP traffic for
>   network egress bandwidth, 60% of the maximum write bandwidth goes to
>   persistent disk traffic, leaving 40% for IP traffic. Click below to
>   see an example of how to calculate the maximum persistent disk write
>   traffic that a VM instance can issue.

In other words, persistent disk is IP storage that uses the instance's egress bandwidth. Times a  redundancy multiplier, the price of durable writes.

Egress bandwidth quotas are a function of number of vCPUs. 100% persistent disk writes saturates this at they call the write *limit*. As disk bandwidth is has a further quota by disk size, they also calculate the minimum size deliver that.

A more realistic scenario has that competing with non-storage traffic. Resulting an a 60% storage 40% IP split. Storage's share in this traffic shaping scheme is the write *allocation*.

An even more realistic scenario, with a read write distribution, regional persistent disks, plus IP traffic, is an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Looking at the numbers, though, 227 is 94% of 140, and 346/400 is 86% - which doesn't look like its 60%/40% split, at least for some of the examples given. Which leaves me confused as to how those numbers were calculated.

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps their table is wrong, or their quota allocations aren't actually linear.  Instance types already exist that don't follow 2 vCPU = 4 Gb egress.